# Computer switching on but turns off before boot

Tags: boot, post, switching

My PC was working fine 2 days ago, I have switched it onfor a short time to check something, then shut it down properly, seemingly no issues. Yestersay I tried to switch it on again, heard the fans starting and lights came up but after about 3 seconds it seitches off and l the light above the power button is on conatantly. Nothing comes to the screen, no beeps, it looks like it does not go past the POST check. I have checked the PSU by replacing it with my old one, tried to play around with the RAM, tried to boot from my old HDD instead of the SSD, tried my old i3 CPU instead of my newer i7 but nothing seems to solve the problem. The only other thing I can think of is the motherboard itself but the CMOS light is constantly on so there should be no problem there. Any suggestions as to what else should I try or try to replace?

Comment: Make and specific model of PC?

Comment: It is a HP ProDesk 400 G1 but apart from the case and the motherboard nothing is the original. It runs an intel 4790 CPU, GTX 770 Videocard, 8 gigs of RAM (1600 mhz I think), Samsung QVO 1TB SSD, powered by a 650W CoolerMaster PSU. The motherboard is MS-7860 ver 1.2.

Comment: Update: While testing different things (changing sata cable, trying to get the bios up etc.) I have realised that it switches on properly after it has been disconnected from power for a while but if I switch it off then try to switch on again immadiately after, it will not go through POST.